# Error: Cannot convert 'char (*)[15]' to 'char*'

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, char

I'm a beginner C++ programmer. I've tried everything I can think of to fix this error, but I'm completely lost (probably because I'm trying to follow the C logic).

This is part of the code:

```
...
void receive_registration( char *registration);

void insert class(){

    system("cls"); 
    class insertion;
    FILE *arq;

    cout << "*=*=*=*=*=*enter data about the class*=*=*=*=*=*=*=\n" ;
    cout << "#---> data's student:\n\n";

    cout << "\n registration's number of student: ";
    char registration[15];

    cin >> registration;

    receive_registration (& registration); // line with the error
    
    
    fflush(stdin);
    cout << "\n Student's_name:";
    fgets(student_name_insertion,100,stdin);
   
  ...
```

Comment: Following C logic in C++ is not a good idea, it is another language and you should get familar with that languages concepts.

Comment: It is also not a good idea to mix C-style I/O and C++-style I/O. Pick one or the other and stick with it.

Answer (score 2):

`registration` is a `char[15]` array. `&registration` is returning a pointer to the array, ie `char(*)[15]`. But `receive_registration()` wants a `char*` pointer to a single `char` instead. The two pointer types are not compatible, hence the error.

In certain contexts, referring to an array by just its name will *decay* into a pointer to its first element. For instance, when passing the array by value to a function parameter, but not when calling `operator&` on the array. So, if you drop the `&` when calling `receive_registration()`, a `char*` pointer to `registration`'s 1st `char` will be passed:

```
receive_registration(registration);
```

Comment: i found the error that caused the program to print "s%s%s%s%s%s%".
I put "char registration[15];" at the beginning of the code
and called the char at the end of the code rewriting as "char registration[12];"
thanks for the correction in the line "receive registration" :)